# How to get google result when using proxy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-scraping

I have made C# application that gets google image and text result , for submitted urls.

The issue is it always works for the urls using `HTTPWEBREQUEST` but when i use proxy it does not work .I get errors like 302 Document Move`or`502 Server unavailable.

Again if i use webbrowser control it works with proxy .

I did see many question and answer relating to my question but none matches close..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution for my own problem:

We need to use https proxies with google in order of it to work .As this worked for me and make proper host as i was also using multiple urls according to different locations.

This is my code:

```
    public string getHtmltt(string url)
    {

        string responseData = "";
        try
        {
            string host = string.Empty;

            if (url.Contains("/search?"))
            {
                host = url.Remove(url.IndexOf("/search?"));

                if(host.Contains("//"))
                {
                    host = host.Remove(0, host.IndexOf("//")).Replace("//","").Trim();
                }
            }
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Accept = "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
            request.Timeout = 60000;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.KeepAlive = false; ;


           // request.Host = "www.google.com.af";
            request.Host = host;
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");

            //request.Proxy = null;
           // WebProxy prx = new WebProxy("199.231.211.107:3128");

            WebProxy prx = new WebProxy(proxies[0].ToString().Trim());

            request.Proxy = prx;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
            {
                inCookieContainer.Add(cook);
            }
            response.Close();



        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            responseData = "An error occurred: " + e.Message;

        }

        return responseData;

    }
```

And so far its working gr8.